# ArcGIS Pro locking a layout so it does not change when you change the standard map view

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, basemap

I have a map and have created a layout for it, but can't work out how to stop the layout map (and associated scale and extent indicator) changing when I change the standard map view (i.e. enabling/disabling different layers, or changing the symbology). I know how to lock the positions of the features on the layout, but not how to stop them from changing completely.

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking, you say you have a basemap, then a "layout map" but you talk about turning on/off layers which would imply you have a standard map view. To me a basemap is the un-editable background layer you access from the Basemap button on the Map tab? So what is you have? A few screen shots may help?

Comment: Ah sorry - I mean a standard map view rather than a basemap.

Comment: Edit and correct the question (including the title).  As it is the question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: If I'm following you correctly... you need to lock the scale/extent of the data frame under the Map Frame Properties, in layout View. Then no matter what you do in Map view, the extent of your layout will remain static.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't just mean the scale/layout - I mean how do I stop the Map Frame from changing if I change the features of the associated map? (i.e. changing the symbology)

Comment: I don't think you can? You can of course map copies of maps each with a variation of layers turned on/off.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is possible in AGP at the moment.  Here's a relevant thread from ESRI's forums: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/locked-multiple-layouts-in-arcgis-pro/idi-p/924876/page/4#comments.  A somewhat clumsy workaround is to save then copy your first project (so the first one's symbology is fixed) and then in the new project change the symbology.  Another approach would be to have the same layer in a project multiple times with different symbology, and turn them off or on as needed.  I'll note what you are asking for is available in QGIS.

Comment: Oh thank you - this seems like such a basic feature, I just assumed that I couldn't find it! Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @johns Your comment looks like an answer (even if the answer is that it can't be done).